# Create a new array of objects by inserting tags

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, semantic-ui-react

I want to change this array of objects:

```
const arr = [
   {title: "Title 1", content: ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]},
   {title: "Title 2", content: ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]},
   {title: "Title 3", content: ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]},
   {title: "Title 4", content: ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]}
]
```

to this format:

```
const newArr = [
                {
                  title: "<Label color='blue' content='Title 1' />", 
                  content: [
                           "<Message content='Lorem'/>", 
                           "<Message content='ipsum'/>", 
                           "<Message content='dolor'/>"
                          ]
                },
                ....
                ....
                {
                  title: "<Label color='blue' content='Title 4' />", 
                  content: [
                             "<Message content='Lorem'/>", 
                             "<Message content='ipsum'/>", 
                             "<Message content='dolor'/>"
                           ]
                },
               ]
```

Just in case you want to know why, I'm trying to integrate an accordion component from semantic-ui-react. Check [this out](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion#accordion-example-panels-prop-with-custom-title-and-content).

Comment: Your new format looks like something called JSON

Comment: Have you tried creating a JSX on your own?

Comment: @Finiox the format is exactly the same, only the values have changed.

Comment: @Rajesh .. I'm still trying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave it a shot and I think this is what you're looking for:

```js
const arr = [
   {title: "Title 1", content: ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]},
   {title: "Title 2", content: ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]},
   {title: "Title 3", content: ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]},
   {title: "Title 4", content: ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]}
];

const newArr = arr.map(function(obj) {
  return {
    title: "<Label color='blue' content='" + obj.title + "'/>",
    content: obj.content.map(function(c) {
      return "<Message content='" + c + "'/>";
    })
  };
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Yes, This is what I asked for.. Apparently the values shouldn't be strings to get accordion working as expected. However, I can manage the rest. Thank you for the help